# Поиск ошибки в template tags

Tags: python, django, шаблоны, django-template

У меня есть модель:

```
class Perm(models.Model):
user_perm = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                              blank=True, related_name='user_perm')
choices_perm = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=permissions_choice, null=True,)

class Meta:
    unique_together = ['user_perm', 'choices_perm']
```

Я написал декоратор который проверяет ,есть ли разрешение у пользователя. если нет то его редиректит.

```
def user_permissions_handler(need_permissions_constant):
def get_view(view):
    def get_params(request):
        user_permissions = Perm.objects.filter(user_perm=request.user)\
            .values_list('choices_perm', flat=True)
        if user_is_need_permissions(user_permissions, need_permissions_constant):
            print(user_permissions, ' первый принт')
            print(need_permissions_constant, ' второй принт')
            return view(request)
        else:
            return redirect('permissions:error_permissions')
    return get_params
return get_view


def user_is_need_permissions(user_permissions, need_permissions_constant):
    if need_permissions_constant in user_permissions:
        return True
    return False
```

Это таблица разрешений:

```
edit_user = 'edit_user'
view_all = 'view_all'
create_user = 'create_user'
delete_user = 'delete_user'
add_user = 'add_user'
permissions_choice = [
    (edit_user, 'Can edit user '),
    (view_all, 'Can view all'),
    (create_user, 'Can create user'),
    (delete_user, 'Can delete user'),
    (add_user, 'Can add user'),
```

]

Теперь мне нужно написать template tag что бы проверять разрешения в темплэйтах(например вешать перед кнопками, если есть разрешение кнопка видна, если нет скрыта)
Вот что мне удалось написать, но не работает. помогите пожалуйста разобраться

```
from django import template
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from ..models import Perm
register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='has_perm')
def has_perm(user, need_permissions_constant, request):
    user_permissions = Perm.objects.filter(user_perm=request.user) \
        .values_list('choices_perm', flat=True)

    if need_permissions_constant in user_permissions:
        return need_permissions_constant
    else:
         return ""


 '''
 {% load  permissions_check %}
     {% if request.user|has_perm:"view_all" %}
   {% endif %}
 '''
```

Comment: Сделай `print(user_permissions)` в темплейт теге и посмотри, какие там значения.

Comment: <QuerySet ['edit_user', 'create_user', 'delete_user', 'view_all']>

Comment: попробуй `if need_permissions_constant in list(user_permissions):`

Comment: И почему в фильтре три параметра?

Comment: а какой  мне нужно убрать? и как ,что бы без проблем

Comment: Я попутал... Она вообще не заходит в функцию в template tag.
@register.filter(name='has_perm')
def has_perm(user, need_permissions_constant):
    user_permissions = Perm.objects.get('choices_perm') \
        .values_list('choices_perm', flat=True)
    print(user_permissions)  ----  ничего не печатает

Comment: покажи структуру приложения, и весь шаблон.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120077/discussion-between-anton-balmakov-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. фильтр должен находится в пакете `templatetags`, на одном уровне с `models.py`
2. В шаблоне нужно загрузить фильтр по имени `.py` модуля, в котором он находится.

`{% load permissions_check %}`

3. Использовать фильтр в шаблоне (важный нюанс: если параметр строка - должен быть в кавычках).

`request.user|has_perm:"view_all"`

4. В твоём фильтре параметр `request` - лишний. В фильтре два параметра (можно их разделить по `|` в шаблоне. левая часть - первый параметр, правая - второй. Поэтому в фильтре не может быть больше двух параметров). Пользователь у тебя находится в переменной `user`.
5. `.filter(name='has_perm')` - писать здесь необязательно. `name` стоит использовать, когда хочешь задать имя фильтру, отличительное от названия функции.

Поэтому фильтр будет выглядеть так:

```
@register.filter
def has_perm(user, need_permissions_constant):
    user_permissions = Perm.objects.filter(user_perm=user) \
        .values_list('choices_perm', flat=True)
    res = False
    if need_permissions_constant in user_permissions:
        res = True
    return res
```

Или одной строкой

```
@register.filter
def has_perm(user, need_permissions_constant):
    return need_permissions_constant in Perm.objects.filter(user_perm=user).values_list('choices_perm', flat=True)
```

*P.S. возможно, `user_permissions` придется преобразовать в `list`. Не уверен, нужно проверить.*

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том что в фильтр передавалось больше 2х аргументов, и паре пробелов по невнимательности.

```
@register.filter(name='has_perm')
def has_perm(user, obj):
print(has_perm)
    user_permissions = Perm.objects.filter(user_perm=user) \
         .values_list('choices_perm', flat=True)
    print(user_permissions)
    if obj in list(user_permissions):
    print(obj)
        return True
    else:
       return ""
```

а в шаблон передаётся таким образом

```
{% load permissions_check %}

{% if request.user|has_perm:'view_all' %}
....
{% endif %}
```